# get_total () returns 0 - woocommerce

Tags: php, wp-admin, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I have some function to get order total value. 
I have a problem, because get_total(); allways returns 0.

I need order total value from backend admin > order details. When i check files i found some string:  $formatted_total and filter for it:
[Class_WC_Abstract_Order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1557-1564) , but i can't show that price.

```
function suma() {
global $wp;
global $woocommerce;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$total = $order->get_total();

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get your orderid, first you need to assign `orderid` then check get_total as shown in below code:

```
global $wp;
global $woocommerce;
$order_id = 11;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$total = $order->get_total();
echo $total;
```

Comment: Still nothing. I tried set order_id to my checking order = for example 1, 2, 14. 
I tried get order ID $order_id = new WC_Order($post->ID);  but still returns 0.

Comment: Anybody help me?

Comment: Please `echo $post->ID;` before you pass it as argument in WC_Order() and check it is valid order number.